# Is 'Robin Hood, reversed' a sentence?

Tags: punctuation, sentence, is-it-a-rule

In an extremely well written and justifiably incisive [article](https://www.msn.com/en-gb/money/news/in-britain-austerity-is-changing-everything/ar-AAxUEiy?li=BBoPWjQ&ocid=mailsignout) on British austerity measures since the credit crunch of 2008, Peter Goodman of The New York Times writes the following :

> In these communities, Mrs. Thatcher’s name is an epithet, and austerity is the latest villain: London bankers concocted a financial crisis, multiplying their wealth through reckless gambling; then London politicians used budget deficits as an excuse to cut spending on the poor while handing tax cuts to corporations. Robin Hood, reversed.

The writer uses a colon, then (unusually for modern writing) a semi colon and I wonder if he has baulked at using another colon.

Is 'Robin Hood, reversed' a sentence in its own right ?

Or should it be added after yet another colon ?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with it.  This is abbreviated text for something like "This is Robin Hood, reversed", and is perfectly legit in all but stodgy formal contexts.  (And a sentence with TWO colons and a semicolon would make many a mind short-circuit.)

Comment: I'd see it as a summary explanation of the preceding paragraph. The colon is either for a list or an explanation and where it's used, I think it's both (a list of explanations as to why austerity is a villain). Using a second colon within that list would syntactically break it, plus the sentence summarises the whole paragraph, not just one of the explanatory list items.

Comment: The first colon should be a full stop.The reader expects explication/development of "austerity," but that doesn't come until the end of the next clause. Then Robin Hood can get a colon.

Comment: "Robin Hood reversed." adds emphasis.  Effective.  (It made you sit up and take notice! :))  This construction should be used sparingly, however.

Comment: It seems to me that sentences cast as, in effect, work-of-art titles have gained some popularity in conversational writing, at least since 1993/1999—the year when the novel/film [_Girl, Interrupted_](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0172493/) appeared. Most notable to my eye is the comma between the subject (_Girl_ in one instance; _Robin Hood_ in the other) and its modifier/quasi-verb (_Interrupted_; _reversed_). But perhaps this phenomenon is just a complete coincidence, rather than a sign of a pop-culture tendency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the article [Verbless Sentences](http://queens-english-society.org/verbless-sentences/) by Bill Ball on the website of The Queen's English Society, your example of a verbless sentence is OK.  First, what is a verbless sentence, and is your example verbless:

> Although there have always been verbless sentences in English, many
>   grammarians of old insisted that a sentence had to contain at least
>   one 'finite' verb. Examples of finite verbs are 'is', as in 'The
>   weather is fine', and 'plays', as in 'He plays tennis'. The word
>   'finite' broadly means 'having a subject'. In the above examples, the
>   subjects of the verbs are 'The weather' and 'He'.

The author then gives several examples of verbless sentences, of which ***A wonderful achievement.*** could be an ironic commentary on Peter Goodman's *Robin Hood, reversed*.

Next the author cautions about the use of verbless sentences:

> Indeed, there are still some people today who would condemn verbless
>   sentences, even though they are and always have been acceptable
>   English.
>
> It has to be admitted, however, that verbless sentences should never
>   be used in formal writing (legal documents and the like) or by
>   schoolchildren or students in their school or college work. It is
>   often said that it is acceptable for established writers to commit
>   occasional grammatical errors, because they have learnt all the rules
>   and therefore have the right to modify them to suit their purpose if
>   they so wish. That may be so, but there is one 'rule' that says that
>   verbless sentences should be used sparingly and with good taste. Any
>   writers who choose to ignore this rule (for whatever reason) do so at
>   their own risk.

In the example the OP gave, the verblessness of the concluding sentence added emphasis.  ***This is Robin Hood in reverse*** would have had a much lower POW!- factor.